# Why does changing the order of quantifiers in Goldbach's conjecture changes its meaning and truth value?

Tags: logic

Goldbach's conjecture in English reads:

> “Every even integer greater than 2 is the sum of two primes.”

Which can be written in terms of quantifiers as:

> $$\forall n  \in \text{Even}. \exists p \in \text{Primes} \exists q \in \text{Primes}. n= p +q. $$

Where Even =  {set of all even numbers greater than or equal 2} and Primes = {the set of all primes numbers}.

I was told that changing the order of the quantifiers a little bit changes the meaning of the statement, but I don't understand why it does that:

> $$ \exists p \in \text{Primes} \exists q \in \text{Primes}. \forall n  \in \text{Even}. n=p +q. $$

How is the second one different? I was told that it means in English that:

> Every even number $\geq 2$ is the sum of the same two primes.

However, I cannot convince myself that, that is correct. Also, how come that the second interpretation is false?

Comment: Why is the second one false? Suppose it is true and let $p,q$ have the property that $\forall n\in 2\mathbb N(n=p+q)$. Then in particular one gets $4=p+q=2$. As for they having different meanings, if the GC happens to be false, then some people defend that they have the same meaning.

Comment: This question, [Interpretation of quantifiers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690167/interpretation-of-quantifiers), is substantially similar.

Comment: @MJD Thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is standard practice in mathematics to instantiate quantifiers from left to right.  Hence the standard way to interpret the second statement is: there is a prime $p$, and a prime $q$, such that for all even $n$, the equation $n=p+q$ holds.

That is, $p,q$ are chosen before $n$ is instantiated, so the statement must hold without changing either $p$ or $q$, for *every* $n$.  This is absurd, and false.

In English we often rely on context to disambiguate sentences, so we are used to interpreting them "however makes sense"; however in mathematics we want extra precision, including the ability to make statements that are absurd if we so desire.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious to you, but what do you mean that, "it must hold for the same p and q"? The same p and q, means $p = q$? Your explanation that if we fix p and q, then p+q is some number say k, and that number cannot possibly be every even number once p and q are fixed. That does make sense. However, I just don't understand what the word "same" means here though.

Comment: Sorry, will clarify.  Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with a simpler example :

> $\forall n \in \mathbb N \exists m \in \mathbb N (n < m)$.

It is clearly *true*, because for every *natural* number $n$ we can always find a greater number $m$ : it is enough to choose as $m$ the number $n+1$.

Now, swapping the quantifiers we get :

> $\exists m \in \mathbb N \forall n \in \mathbb N (n < m)$

that must be read as : there exists a *natural* number $m$ that is greater then every number $n$, which is clearly *false*.